# Acesso a pontos específicos da memória

Tags: c, c++, windows, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória

Como eu faço para acessar um endereço exato na memória no Windows?

```
unsigned char * mem = {??};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você não consegue acessar um endereço aleatório assim, na maioria das situações. Hoje há proteção para acesso à memória.

Em alguns casos você conseguirá acessar fazendo:

```
#include <cstdint>

uintptr_t p = 0x0001FFFF;
int value = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(p);
```

Nada garante que o acesso funcionará como você espera. O resultado pode ser diferente dependendo da situação.

Achei esta outra [resposta do Guilherme Bernal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549245/221800) que mostra como fazer algo que funcione mas novamente não dará resultados consistentes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
    unsigned pageSize = sysinfo.dwPageSize;
    printf("page size: %d\n", pageSize);
    void* target = (void*)0x4e0f68;
    printf("trying to allocate exactly one page containing 0x%p...\n", target);
    void* ptr = VirtualAlloc(target, pageSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (ptr) printf("got: 0x%p\n", ptr); //   ptr <= target < ptr+pageSize
    else printf("failed! OS wont let us use that address.\n");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/InternalMemory.c).

Note que esta situação é um pouco mais controlada.

Em C o `void *` significa que está usando um ponteiro para qualquer coisa.

Comment: Obrigado brother, ^^ funcionou para o que eu queria hahaha

Answer (score 5):

O teu sistema operativo não vai permitir que acedas a memória que não pertence ao teu programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *mem = 0xdeadbeef; // ou = 3735928559;
    printf("O endereco %p tem %d\n", (void*)mem, *mem);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Permite sim, mas meu programa precisa estar na mesma ara de memoria que o programa alvo